# Pass data from view to controller using ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC and web development (I work mainly with c# and desktop development) and I have a big problem:

I try to pass data from my view to the controller, but everything I try ends up in an empty or null parameter in my controllers action...

I tried many approaches from different tutorials on the web but nothing worked, there must be something I am doing wrong in major.

I've created a simple project to demonstrate my problem:

My View:

```
@model TestJsonBinding.Models.TestModel


<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("TestTransfer", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <p>Name: <input id="txbName" type="text" value="@Model.Name" /></p>
        <p>Alter: <input id="txbAge" type="number" value="@Model.Age" /></p>
        <p></p>
        <a id="btnSend" onclick="send()"> Send </a>
    }
</body>

<script>
    function send() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TestTransfer",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: GetModelJson(),
            success: function (result) {

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.text);
            }
        })
    }


    function GetModelJson() {
        var customModel = new Object();
        customModel.Name = $("#txbName").attr("value");
        customModel.Age = Number($("#txbAge").attr("value"));

        alert(JSON.stringify({ JsonDataTransfer: customModel }));

        return JSON.stringify({ JsonDataTransfer: customModel });
    }

</script>
```

My controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestJsonBinding.Models;

namespace TestJsonBinding.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new TestModel() { Name = "Parker", Age = 27});
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TestTransfer(TestModel model)
        {
            return Json(model);
        }

    }
}
```

My model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestJsonBinding.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

That's the JSON my alert shows:

{"JsonDataTransfer":{"Name":"Parker","Age":27}}

and thats what I'm getting in the controller:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TgLq.png)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need AJAX call to post the model to the controller action. Just submit the form. Instead of:

```
<a id="btnSend" onclick="send()"> Send </a>
```

Use:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
```

If for any reason you want to stick on AJAX, change your method like:

```
function GetModelJson() {
        var customModel = new Object();
        customModel.Name = $("#txbName").attr("value");
        customModel.Age = Number($("#txbAge").attr("value"));

        alert(JSON.stringify({ TestModel: customModel }));

        return JSON.stringify({ TestModel: customModel });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I really need ajax. this is a testproject, the main project I need to get the model to the controller needs ajax at some points.

I tried your changes with the json, but it is still not working.

There must be some thing in major wrong with the project, i started a new asp.net mcv project and only editet the premade "Index.cshtml". Like yours, no excample from the internet worked for me.

Is there a special .NET framework I should use to get this working?
Currently I use 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

First of all u needn't to wrap ur object to one more object. I mean ur alert should show:

```
{"Name":"Parker","Age":27}
```

For it simply change this line:

```
return JSON.stringify({ JsonDataTransfer: customModel });
```

To:

```
return JSON.stringify(customModel);
```

And change method sign to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestTransfer([FromBody]TestModel model)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer.

I tried to test your approach but I can't add the needed namespace "using System.Web.Http;" so [FromBody] is not available.

I use ASP.NET MVC with .NET 4.5

Comment: When I delete "TestModel :" from the parameters in stringify, then the call of my functrion "TestTransfer" don't work anymore